# Does the constructor not support the specialization of template functions?

Tags: c++

I tried to let my class's constructor function became a specialization template function, but I failed the compilation. Does the constructor not support the specialization of template functions? If do, how can I add specialization template function to my class's constructor function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Bignum {
private:
    vector<char> vec;
public:
    template <class Type> Bignum(const vector<Type> &num) {
        vec = num;
    }
    template <class Type> Bignum(Type &num) {
        while (num) {
            vec.push_back(num % 10);
            num /= 10;
        }
    }
    template <> Bignum(const string &str) {
        auto __first = str.rbegin();
        auto __last = str.rend();
        for (auto i = __first; i <= __last; ++i) {
            vec.push_back(*i);
        }
    }
    template <class Type> Bignum(const Type *__first, const Type *__last) {
        for (const Type *i = __last; i >= __first; --i) {
            vec.push_back(*i);
        }
    }
    template<> Bignum(char *__first, char *__last) {
        for (char * i = __last; i >= __first; --i) {
            vec.push_back(*i - '0');
        }
    }
    Bignum () {
        
    }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const Bignum &num) {
        auto __first = num.vec.rbegin();
        auto __last = num.vec.rend();
        for (auto i = __first; i < __last; ++i) {
            os << (char)(*i + '0') << ' ';
        }
        os << (char)(*__last + '0') << endl;
        return os;
    }
    size_t size() const {
        return vec.size();
    }
    const char & at(const size_t &pos) const {
        return vec.at(vec.size() - pos);
    }
    const char & operator [] (const size_t &pos) {
        return vec.at(pos);
    }
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    return 0;
}
```

I received a compilation error at line 29 which says No function template matches function template specialization 'Bignum'.

Comment: Is this really a proper [mre]? Is the error you show the full and complete build log? And which line is line number 29? Please add a comment on that line.

Comment: Just remove the `template<>` from both places. It makes no sense whatsoever. You should almost never specialise a function template. Overload instead. There are many more problems in this code that will likely prevent it from working though.

Comment: Clang and MSVC accept the specializations after you fix the `const` mismatch in both. GCC wants them to be outside of the class. But you don't need the specializations, you can just overload the constructor.

Comment: Also note that identifiers containing `__` are reserved and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you just need to remove the template <> from the constructors that do not need to be member function templates.

However, it may be beneficial to consider how to accomplish what you may be after in a more generic fashion.

---

How you actually intend to store the data is confusing, because your implementation does different things (some expect it to be stored in "little-endian" and others expect it in "big-endian" order).  In addition, some of your functions expect the data to be stored in the range [0, 9] and others seem to expect data in the range ['0', '9'].

However, none of that is relevant to what I think is the real question, which is about the constructor interface, so I will assume that data is stored as ASCII digits ['0', '9'] and in the order they would be printed as a string - just to pick something.

I would also suggest you use a specific strong type `Digit`, as the internal representation, which would remove all ambiguity as to the meaning.  It would also remove all change of undesired conversions.

---

It looks like you want to be able to create a BigNum out of anything that can be used to create a vector of char.

This constructor does that.  Note that we explicitly disable taking a single integral type, because you can create a vector from one of those, but it does not seem to be what you want, since you have another constructor that appears to take an integral.

```cpp
template <
    typename... ArgTs,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_constructible_v<std::vector<char>, ArgTs...> &&
            not ((sizeof...(ArgTs) == 1) && ... && std::is_integral_v<ArgTs>),
        bool> = true>
explicit Bignum(ArgTs && ... args)
: vec(std::forward<ArgTs>(args)...)
{
    // If not using a strong type, should at least assert that the
    // data you get is what you expect.
    assert(vec.size() == std::count_if(
        vec.begin(),
        vec.end(),
        [](unsigned char c){ return std::isdigit(c); }));
}
```

Then, you can take any unsigned integral type like this (I restricted it to unsigned because it does not look like your code is prepared to handle signed values).

```cpp
template <
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_unsigned_v<T>,
        bool> = true>
Bignum(T number)
{
    while (number) {
        vec.push_back((number % 10) + '0');
        number /= 10;
    }
    std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

And, to accept a string, you do not need a member function template...

```cpp
Bignum(std::string_view s)
: Bignum(s.begin(), s.end())
{ }
```

Finally, I'll encourage you to become familiar with the standard algorithms.  For example,

```cpp
friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, Bignum const & num)
{
    std::copy(num.vec.begin(), num.vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(os));
    return os;
}
```